# Altering Weighted incremental algorithm for calculating moving variance

Tags: algorithms, means, variance

Using the algorithm described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance)  to calculate the variance while data streams, I want to compute a moving variance, which like in the case of moving average will consider older data less important.

for convinence here the algorithm from the wiki page :

```
def weighted_incremental_variance(dataWeightPairs):
    wSum = 0
    mean = 0
    S = 0

    for x, w in dataWeightPairs:  # Alternatively "for x, w in zip(data, weights):"
        wSum = wSum + w
        meanOld = mean
        mean = meanOld + (w / wSum) * (x - meanOld)
        S = S + w * (x - meanOld) * (x - mean)

    variance = S / wSum
```

altering this algorithm for moving mean is easy (i think) just divide wSum by some factor>1 (the larger the more forgetfull it becomes). but given this factor, how would i fix S to act accordingly?

I could divide it by the same factor as well but that doesnt feel right...

Answer (score 1):

To put this into
symbolic terms,
you want to compute
a uniformly weighted moving average
of $n$ previous terms
by

$y(i)
=c_n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^j x_{i-j}
$,
where $c_n$ is chosen
so that
$c_n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^j
=1
$.

This is to ensure that
the weighted average of
a constant series
returns the same value.

Getting $c_n$ is straightforward.

If $w=1$,
$c_n = 1/n$.

If $w \ne 1$,
$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^j
=\dfrac{1-w^n}{1-w}
$
so
$c_n
=\dfrac{1-w}{1-w^n}
$.

To do this efficiently,
we want to get $y(i+1)$
in terms of $y(i)$.
(What follows is fairly standard
subscript manipulation.)

$\begin{array}\\
y(i+1)
&=c_n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^j x_{i+1-j}\\
&=c_n(x_{i+1}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} w^j x_{i+1-j})\\
&=c_n(x_{i+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} w^{j+1} x_{i-j})\\
&=c_n(x_{i+1}+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^{j+1} x_{i-j}-w^{n}x_{i-n+1})\\
&=c_n(x_{i+1}+w\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^{j} x_{i-j}-w^{n}x_{i-n+1})\\
&=c_n(x_{i+1}+wy(i)/c_n-w^{n}x_{i-n+1})\\
&=wy(i)+c_n(x_{i+1}-w^{n}x_{i-n+1})\\
\end{array}
$

While this does require
that the last $n+1$
$x_i$ values need to be stored
(a circular buffer will 
do this quite nicely),
the computation takes only
a constant time
instead of time
$\Theta(n)$
by the straightforward values.

Note that to do this
efficiently like this
requires that the weights
be of the form $w^j$.
If the weights are arbitrary,
the full computation 
has to be done each time.

It would be an interesting problem
to determine the most general weights
such that 
$y(i+1)$ could be computed from
$y(i)$
in constant time
independent of $n$.

I think that
I'll propose this
as a problem.

Comment: nice detailed answer, though Im not sure we are on the same page, i was looking for moving variance, not moving average...

Comment: Once you get the successive values, you can use an online method, such as Kahan's, to get the variance.